# ONT methylation data normalization

Tags: statistics, quantile, weighted-average

I have methylation data from ONT sequencing expressed as percentage of methylation and/or number of reads. I don't know if I'm supposed to normalize the data and how to handle replicates.
Some ideas: I have data in triplicate. I want to normalize the data (quantile normalization is the preferred option) and/or collapse data to have 1 file/dataset from 3 replicates (doing weigthed average maybe).
So 1 idea would be just to perform weighted average of each methylation value doing [%M*NR] where %M is the percentage of methylated reads and NR is number of reads, per each methylated position.
In this case I will lose the meaning of the percentage value in the downstream analyses because I will have a wheigted value.
otherwhise I can perform quantile normalization on the number of reads (total and methylated) and then calculate percentage of methylated reads.
I would like the opinion of somewone with a better statistical background than me ;)
thansk for your kind help!

```
       %M-S1  NR-S1 %M-S2  NR-S2 %M-S3  NR-S3
Meth1   20     60     15     54    41     12
Meth2   40     14     78     52    13     65
Meth3   12     94     73     19    37     70
Meth4   36     77     69     14    26     74
```

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try chemistry.stackexchange.com instead.